# VisualSVN Server giving 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to commit some files to a Subversion repository hosted in VisualSVN server, it's started giving me an error message I haven't seen before:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to  
Error:  MKCOL request for  
Error:  '/svn/XXX/!svn/txr/1005-tj/XXX.co.uk/trunk/www/1/App_Data/files/2011/9'
```

I've recently updated my server to 2.5.2, which incorporates Subversion 1.72. Could this be a breakage in the new version or is someone familiar with what's wrong here?

Comment: That can happen if connection between client and server was dropped mid-operation and client retried the operation.